# Library-Installation in Python unsuccesful

Tags: python, windows

I'm currently trying to install the Python-Library *yfinance*.
For that I have used the command `pip install yfinance` which succeeded with multiple warnings regarding something about the Paths (can't recall exactly).

I used `pip show yfinance` to verfy that the library is indeed installed, which it is.

However, files containing `import yfinance` return an error message: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yfinance'`.

I then figured that I maybe installed the library in the wrong directory so I retried with the following command: `pip install --target=d:C:\Users\useR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib yfinance --no-user`
(that is the directory which also contains preinstalled librarys like *tkinter*)

That results in the following:

```
Collecting yfinance
  Using cached yfinance-0.1.67-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting pandas>=0.24
  Using cached pandas-1.3.4-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (10.2 MB)
Collecting requests>=2.20
  Using cached requests-2.26.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
Collecting multitasking>=0.0.7
  Using cached multitasking-0.0.10.tar.gz (8.2 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting numpy>=1.15
  Using cached numpy-1.21.4-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (14.0 MB)
Collecting lxml>=4.5.1
  Using cached lxml-4.6.4-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (3.5 MB)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.7.3
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
Collecting pytz>=2017.3
  Using cached pytz-2021.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (503 kB)
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1
  Using cached urllib3-1.26.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Using cached certifi-2021.10.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (149 kB)
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5
  Using cached idna-3.3-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer~=2.0.0
  Using cached charset_normalizer-2.0.9-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting six>=1.5
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for multitasking, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: six, urllib3, pytz, python-dateutil, numpy, idna, charset-normalizer, certifi, requests, pandas, multitasking, lxml, yfinance
    Running setup.py install for multitasking ... done
Successfully installed certifi-2021.10.8 charset-normalizer-2.0.9 idna-3.3 lxml-4.6.4 multitasking-0.0.10 numpy-1.21.4 pandas-1.3.4 python-dateutil-2.8.2 pytz-2021.3 requests-2.26.0 six-1.16.0 urllib3-1.26.7 yfinance-0.1.67
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\useR\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 164, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\useR\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 205, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\useR\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 463, in run
    self._handle_target_dir(
  File "C:\Users\useR\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 473, in _handle_target_dir
    ensure_dir(target_dir)
  File "C:\Users\useR\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 103, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\os.py", line 215, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\os.py", line 215, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\os.py", line 215, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  [Previous line repeated 6 more times]
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\os.py", line 225, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'D:\\'
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for reading, sorry for my English and lack of competence ^^ :)

Comment: Are you sure that this is the full console output? Usually after `FileNotFound` error there are several lines more with extra info, can you post them if they exist?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I reinstalled Python. That solved to problem.